# Как заставить включаться компьютер автоматически после отключения электричества?

Tags: железо

Есть на даче мини сервер на основе Intel Celeron 1900 - материнка MSI J1900I. Он должен постоянно работать. Однако иногда в поселке отключают электричество и когда включают его комп не включается - надо нажать кнопку включения.
Можно ли как то замкнуть контакты, чтобы после включения электричества он включался и загружался автоматически?

Answer (score 3):

Зайди в БИОС. Settings - Power management - Выстави Restore after AC Power Loss в нужный режим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]